# Error en sentencia SQL con Count Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta SQL a una base de datos para obtener la cantidad de piezas, por cada puesto-fase y he usado la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
    maquina AS PUESTO,
    fase AS FASE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pieza) AS PIEZAS
FROM tabla1
LEFT JOIN tabla2 on tabla1.pieza=tabla2.pieza
LEFT JOIN table3 on tabla2.bol=tabla3.bol
WHERE bol ='bol1'
AND convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, fecha, 106),103) >= CAST('30/11/2018' AS DATE) 
AND convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, fecha, 106),103) <= CAST('30/11/2018' AS DATE)
AND tabla1.pieza NOT LIKE ''
GROUP BY PUESTO, FASE
ORDER BY PUESTO
```

y me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me repite la cuenta de piezas para cada puesto y fase, cuando lo que quiero es ver solo la cuenta de cada puesto-fase

Comment: Deberías mostrar la estructura de las tablas para que nos enteremos de las relaciones

Comment: Las relaciones son correctas, si q consigue llegar a la información

Comment: Ya, llegar llega, pero no con la agrupación que el pretende, por lo tanto le debe faltar alguna relación en el JOIN o algún campo en el GROUP, aunque esto ultimo no parece ser lo esperado.

Comment: En el grouo seguro que no, dado que solo hay un campo mas y si lo uniera seria única y me saldran muuuuuuchas líneas, en el Join...

Comment: compartenos la estructura y la forma en que estan relacionadas las tablas para oderte ayudar de una mejor manera

Comment: Si solo quieres cuantas puestos y fases hay, ¿por qué no pruebas count(1) en lugar de count(distinct pieza)? Si lo que quieres es la suma de las piezas por puesto y fase, eso es otra cosa.

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir una pequeña muestra de los datos que hay en las 3 tablas y la salida que esperas obtener con dichos datos?. Te invito a leer como crear un [mcve].

Comment: @JYass quiero cuantas piezas hay por puesto y fase, por eso uso el count(distinct......) pero me sale el mismo recuento para todos los puestos cuando no es así

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a cambiar el group de la sentencia a

```sql
GROUP BY CONCAT(PUESTO, '_', FASE)
```

Con esa parte de la sentencia vas a generar un sólo campo en combinación con `PUESTO` y `FASE` por cada fila, y se van a agrupar las filas internamente por esa combinación de valores.

Comment: @marcss, si la respuesta te ha sido útil puedes marcarla como que ha resuelto tu pregunta en vez de darle +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener las filas en común haz un inner join en lugar de left join.
Es decir:

```
SELECT 
    maquina AS PUESTO,
    fase AS FASE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pieza) AS PIEZAS
FROM tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla2 on tabla1.pieza=tabla2.pieza
INNER JOIN table3 on tabla2.bol=tabla3.bol
WHERE bol ='bol1'
AND convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, fecha, 106),103) >= CAST('30/11/2018' AS DATE) 
AND convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, fecha, 106),103) <= CAST('30/11/2018' AS DATE)
AND tabla1.pieza NOT LIKE ''
GROUP BY PUESTO, FASE
ORDER BY PUESTO
```

Comment: No, me sigue mostrando la misma cantidad de recuento de piezas para todos los puestos :(

Answer (score 0):

To get the rows in common, do a natural inner join instead of left join. That is to say:

```
SELECT 
    maquina AS PUESTO,
    fase AS FASE,
    COUNT(distinct pieza) AS PIEZAS
FROM tabla1
NATURAL INNER JOIN tabla2
NATURAL INNER JOIN table3 
WHERE bol ='bol1'
AND convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, fecha, 106),103) >= CAST('30/11/2018' AS DATE) 
AND convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, fecha, 106),103) <= CAST('30/11/2018' AS DATE)
AND (tabla1.pieza) NOT LIKE ''
GROUP BY PUESTO, FASE
ORDER BY PUESTO;
```

Comment: Douglas, este es StackOverflow **en español**. Por favor, publica tus respuestas en la lengua de Cervantes.